# INSERT Table2.Column INTO Table1 only if doesn't exist in Table1 for Table1.ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to insert records into `table1` by matching one column value of `table2` for every `ID` of `table1`. If it doesn't exist then insert that column value for that `ID`. How can I achieve that?

`table1` contains `roleID` and `ScreenCode` with access type for that `roleID`:

[image]

`table2` contains `ScreenCodes`:

[image]

Problem is when new screen is added its access type `N` should be added for every role in `UserLoginRoleAccess` table.

Comment: Can you add sample table data, and expected INSERT behavior?

Comment: @Ziddu . . . The answer is "use  trigger".  But why bother?  You can just add the roles as you need them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff okay! I'll use trigger for future but for now ... I need a solution to update current roles for my application! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Id in(select top 1 Table2.column from Table2 ) THEN
   --Do what you want
ELSE
    --Insert 
   INSERT INTO TABLE1(Values) VALUES('')
   SELECT TableID FROM Table WHERE TableID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

try this, hope this will help

Comment: How to pick up 'ScreenCode' from 'Table2' for insert which doesn't exist in 'Table1'? @Sudhir

Comment: ok use cte to get all RoleId of Table1 then pass it to select Table1 data and then check..

Basically you have to put all RoleId To check ScreenCode Exist or not